# Signals - SIGPIPE was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, signals

I have a project that i am porting from qt 4 to qt 5. I am getting the error mentioned in title. I have included header file(signal.h). Below is the code .

```
signal(SIGPIPE,SIG_IGN);
```

I have searched on internet but could not find any reason for this error. also just to note if I place SIGINT in place of SIGPIPE then I don't get any error.

Any help is appreciated.

Qt version 5.7 on windows 10

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  Also, what OS/platform is being used?

Comment: I am using windows 10

Answer (score 1):

The [Microsoft Windows page for "signal"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/signal) (as of its edit date of 2/12/2018 at least), in its Remarks section, says that the "sig" argument (`SIGPIPE`) must be one of the constants listed. `SIGPIPE` is not listed however.

Looks like not only are you trying to port between different Qt versions, but that you're also trying to port between a Unix-like operating system (like Linux) to the Windows operating system.

To solve this problem, either:

1. At least compile time conditionally rip out the `SIGPIPE` handling code (using something like `#ifdef SIGPIPE` pre-processor commands to exclude the `SIGPIPE` code from platforms that don't support `SIGPIPE`), or
2. Don't try to port your code to any operating systems that don't support `SIGPIPE`.

By the way, this seems to have nothing to do with Qt's signals (signals and slots) mechanism (as this question was originally tagged with).